# Catkin _make failed when I altered an existing GitHub repository of an 2 wheel bot package for a four wheel bot

Tags: i2c

50%] Linking CXX executable /home/happy/guna_ws/devel/lib/autonomous/i2c_ros
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x24): undefined reference to` main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [autonomous/CMakeFiles/i2c_ros.dir/build.make:126: /home/happy/guna_ws/devel/lib/autonomous/i2c_ros] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:499: autonomous/CMakeFiles/i2c_ros.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp: In constructor ‘ROBOTHardwareInterface::ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle&)’:
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:5:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C()’
5 | ROBOTHardwareInterface::ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh) {
|                                                                             ^
In file included from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/robot_hardware_interface.h:14,
from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:1:
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note: candidate: ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(int, int)’
12 |    I2C(int, int);
|    ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(const i2c_ros::I2C&)’
9 |  class I2C
|        ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:5:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C()’
5 | ROBOTHardwareInterface::ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh) {
|                                                                             ^
In file included from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/robot_hardware_interface.h:14,
from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:1:
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note: candidate: ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(int, int)’
12 |    I2C(int, int);
|    ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(const i2c_ros::I2C&)’
9 |  class I2C
|        ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:5:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C()’
5 | ROBOTHardwareInterface::ROBOTHardwareInterface(ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh) {
|                                                                             ^
In file included from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/robot_hardware_interface.h:14,
from /home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp:1:
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note: candidate: ‘i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(int, int)’
12 |    I2C(int, int);
|    ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:12:4: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr i2c_ros::I2C::I2C(const i2c_ros::I2C&)’
9 |  class I2C
|        ^~~
/home/happy/guna_ws/src/autonomous/include/autonomous/i2c_ros.h:9:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make[2]: *** [autonomous/CMakeFiles/mobile_robot_hardware_interface.dir/build.make:63: autonomous/CMakeFiles/mobile_robot_hardware_interface.dir/src/robot_hardware_interface_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1525: autonomous/CMakeFiles/mobile_robot_hardware_interface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

This is the error.Kindly help me resolve it.Thank you.

Comment: Please format your question probably and give more details about your setup, versions etc

Answer (score 0):

One work-around is to wire your motors in parallel (on each side), and trick the robot software into thinking it is two-wheel powered, when really it is four wheel powered.